# CMAKE static library builds well but shared library linking fails

Tags: c++, cmake, build

I have a simple c++ program with following structure.  I use cmake in visual studio to build it.

**Project Description:**

- There is a root level which has main file named *module.cpp* along with *module.h*.
- Root has a subfolder *src* which has two other folders *iMath* and *utils*.
- *utils* folder has a *myprint.h* as well as *myprint.cpp*
- *iMath* is  built as ***library***. it has 2 folders inside it, *include* folder has a header file *addition.h* while *src* folder has a *addition.cpp*.

**Problem detail:**

When iMath is build as a static library, it builds well. However, when it is built as shared library, it results in ***LNK1104 cannot open file src\iMath\MathLib.lib*** error.

[image]

*CMakeLists.txt* at ***Root*** level:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project (module4)
set(UTILS_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/utils)

# add subdirectory
add_subdirectory(src)


# Add source to this project's executable.

add_executable (
calculator
module.cpp 
${UTILS_SOURCE_DIR}/myprint.cpp
)

target_include_directories(calculator PUBLIC ${UTILS_SOURCE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(calculator PUBLIC iMathLib)
```

*CmakeLists.txt* at ***src*** level:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
add_subdirectory(iMath)
```

*CMakeLists.txt* at ***iMath*** level:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project(iMath)

set(SRC_FILES src/addition.cpp )

add_library(iMathLib SHARED ${SRC_FILES})

target_include_directories(iMathLib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

*module.h* at ***ROOT*** level

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "addition.h"
#include "myprint.h"
```

In the last *CMakeLists.txt* at ***iMATH*** level, if i switch ***SHARED*** TO ***STATIC***, everything works well.

Can someone please point me in the right direction as to what should i change so that it builds with *iMath* as ***shared*** as well?

Comment: Why does it need to be shared?

Comment: `set(PROJECT_NAME module4)
project (${PROJECT_NAME})` `project()` sets `PROJECT_NAME` by itself, no need to set it manually. Just `project(module4)`

Comment: @sweenish I would like to create a dll that can then be used in other projects outside of this one

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks, i will make those changes

Comment: Echoing @KamilCuk, it's considered good practice to not name your project and executable the same thing. Quoting **Professional Cmake**: "This only works for the most basic of projects and encourages a number of bad habits."

Comment: @sweenish - I have changed based on your suggestions. Original problem persists but its more readable now

Comment: It seems you forget to **export symbols** from your library. On Windows it is required for being able to use the resulted shared library.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - I added following line set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON) in CMakeLists.txt at iMath level. Now cmake as well as build goes well. However, it gives a runtime error that iMathLib.dll not found. Can you pls further point in right direction.

Comment: For being able to load `.dll` at runtime, either the directory with that dll should be listed in the `PATH` variable, or this dll should be located near the executable which uses it. If you choose the last way, then googling for "cmake copy dll" gives you a lot of possibilities.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: i added following in root CmakeLists.txt and it works now. Thanks. set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})